# Make ics files read only / writable calDAV

Tags: calendar, icalendar, caldav

I have a question regarding calDAV servers and .ics calendar files.

Is it possible, to make certain VEVENTS read-only and others writable?

The user should not be allowed to change every VEVENT in his calendar only some selected by

me.

Thanks!